# Display number of posts from categories using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a custom php blog where I have categories and posts.

In a side widget I have listed all my category titles and next to each of them I'd like to show how many posts they contain.

How can I do that?

My categories table has 2 columns: cat_id and cat_title
My posts table has a post_category_id column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this post first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And post some code that you have written so far

Answer (score 0):

As your question is extremely simple I won't give you the code, but give you the answer so you have to implement it. For solving your problem you have two options:

#### 1. To use `WHERE` statement

You can read about it [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php).

#### 2. To use Inner Join

You can read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

The first one is easier, and as far as I know, it's also faster.

#### Counting the results:

After filtering the results and getting it through PHP, you can get the rows count with `int $mysqli_result->num_rows;` (OO style) or `int mysqli_num_rows ( mysqli_result $result )` (procedural style) ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I'm over complicating things. Here is what I've done: I created a function to display the category titles in my sidebar. The number of posts next to them is just placeholder right now. `function get_cat_titles() {
 $query = query("SELECT * FROM categories");

 while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "
  <li>
  <a href='#'>{$row['cat_title']} &nbsp; <span class='widget-categories__text'>(16)</span>  </a> 
  </li>";
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
 $count = count($mysqli_result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial enough to count the number of posts per category in SQL.

```
select post_category_id, count(*) from posts group by post_category_id;
```

HOWEVER, this query requires a full table scan of your posts, so it is much too slow to do every time your page is accessed. There are several solutions to this problem.

One solution is to add a post_count column to your categories table, and periodically run a query to update your post-counts.

```
update categories
    set categories.post_count = i.cnt
    from (
       select post_category_id, count(*) cnt
           from posts
           group by post_category_id
    ) i
    where categories.cat_id = i.post_category_id
```

Another solution is to add a post_count column to your categories table, and create a trigger for your posts table which automatically updates the counts every time a post is added (or removed). This solution has advantages (the counts are always up to date, and are incrementally updated) and disadvantages (every posting now creates lock contention over the post counts). Trigger code can vary depending on exactly which database you are using, but the insert trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER post_count_trigger ON posts
    AFTER INSERT
    BEGIN
      update categories set post_count=post_count+1 where cat_id=post_categori_id
    END
```